# Return from SELECT and DELETE row in the same query

Tags: mysql

I have the following below run when creating a new member on my system. It gets them an external address to use from a list and then deletes the address used.

My concern is that two people or more may end up with the same address before it gets deleted.

Can I run this query to return an address to $addy and delete it from the table?

```
    $query = "SELECT address FROM ext_address ORDER BY newid ASC LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $addy = $row['address'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ext_address WHERE address='" . $addy . "'");
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM ext_address WHERE address = (SELECT address FROM ext_address ORDER BY newid ASC LIMIT 1)`? Edit: even though this might work, your schema doesn't look as if it's good enough to support multiple addresses..

Comment: @N.B. - you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Why not `SELECT newid FROM ext_address`, then do `DELETE FROM ext_address WHERE newid = ...`?

Comment: You could lock the table to prevent overlaps.